# Why can't kill the process with taskkill?

Tags: windows-7, cmd

how to kill the process

```
>netstat -nao
```

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    10.10.8.10:50931       122.109.119.13:22      ESTABLISHED     4664

```
>taskkill  /pid  4664
```

SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process with PID 4664.

```
 >netstat -nao

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    10.10.8.10:50931       122.109.119.13:22      ESTABLISHED     4664
```

why i can not kill pid 4664 with  `taskkill  /pid  4664`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the following parameters to `TASKKILL`:

```
/T = kill child process

/F = forceful termination
```

Another option would be to use Power Shell to kill by pid:

```
kill -id 4664
```

If nothing works, maybe the process is blocked waiting for some resource (perhaps a bug). Consider rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too elementary, but you may want to
try looking under some of your open windows for a system message..
Ie "do you want to save"
Windows might be being polite and not closing the app before giving you a chance to save or don't save.
it also may be on the screen of the remote computer.